# Snorby Setup-RedCloth error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, snort

I am trying to install Snorby (obviously) and am continuously running into errors with this same gem.  Each time I attempt to do sudo bundle install in the snorby directory, I get the following error:

```
Installing RedCloth (4.2.9) with native extensions /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:556:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)
    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
```

/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `'

I have tried everything I have seen and know.  I have tried to install a previous version of it.  I have tried gem upate.  I have tried sudo gem install Redcloth -v .  It then tells me the same continuous error.  Failed to build gem native extension.  Nothing is working.  All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue finally!  For those of you struggling, search no more.  All you have to do is download the dev package by doing:

sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev